# How can i have @restcontroller and @controller work in same spring boot project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to nest a @RestController jar dependency in side @controller parent project. Both are maven build and spring boot projects. But at once only one of the controller works. For instance if i put package scan in the parent's code i.e @controller's jar file all the features of view resolver is lost but @restcontroller works. By removing the package scan form parent ,@controller works. So can any one help me to get both of the controller types working under same jar??

Comment: Did you try it? Can you share code?

Comment: Spring 4.0 introduced RestController, a specialized version of the controller which is a convenience annotation that does nothing more than adding the Controller and ResponseBody annotations. In that case why do you want to use both of these annotations? By annotating the controller class with RestController annotation, you no longer need to add ResponseBody to all the request mapping methods.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies guys. Found the issue , this was acutally related to two configuration files one in the child and one in the parent jar both having @EnableWebMvc due to which the package scan was making a particular boot project up and other one not to respond. 
Now i shifted the configuration to the the parent ,provided resource locations and  / mapping to the index.html file . Every thing runs as expected (Only the child jar no-loger can be run independently as used to earlier)